# Laravel detect domain

Tags: laravel-5.3

Currently I'm checking the current domain like this:

```
$this->actionUrl     = url('bericht', $send->message->slug);
```

Local this is working but if I push this to production it's telling me that the domain is `localhost`. What would be the right way for things like this should I hard code it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `Request` class:

```
Request::getHost();
```